# Codeigniter from localhost to cpanel using cronjob

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

Good day is there a way in codeigniter using cronjob that i will execute a process in controller like this in my localhost

```
<?php
class Tools extends CI_Controller {

public function message($to = 'World')
{
    echo "Hello {$to}!".PHP_EOL;
}

public function index() {
    echo "hoy";
}

}
```

then i will  create a file for the output of that using cronjob then i will pass it to my cpanel file ?

full example

24 09 * * * php /var/www/codeigniter_folder/index.php tools message > ~/Desktop/output.php

instead of sending the output.php to my desktop i will send it to my cpanel file manager.

thank you in advance

PS: what i want to try is from the localhost i want the output of my controller(which is in the example code) once the cronjob schedule is executed it will generate file in my desktop named output.php but instead of creating it in my desktop i want to redirect to the file manager of cpanel. its like file from localhost then pass it to cpanel.

Comment: unclear. please explain

Comment: @kishor10d what i want to try is from the localhost i want the output of my controller(which is in the example code) once the cronjob schedule is executed it will generate file in my desktop named output.php but instead of creating it in my desktop i want to redirect to the file manager of cpanel. its like file from localhost then pass it to cpanel.

Comment: If you want to create file on server from your cronjob (executing on server) then it is possible. But if you try to execute cronjob from server and want to create file on your desktop - it is not possible.

Comment: @kishor10d I just want is from my localhost the data/output that i will get will be forwarded to cpanel using cronjob.

Comment: first create the file on your desktop and then upload using, for example, a ftp connection to your server

Comment: @David  is it automatically uploaded using ftp or must be manual? because what my clients wants is it must be automatically uploaded in the cpanel

Comment: you should make it 'automatic' , creating a script or a cronjob, it depends on a lot of things, but if you decide using ftp connection, you can use `ftp_put()` ( is a php function )